# Debugging a C++ extension for Python from a Jupyter Notebook in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, vscode-debugger, pybind11

I have a C++ extension for Python (produced using `pybind11`). Debugging this C++ extension from a Python script in Visual Studio Code can be achieved by adding the following configuration in the `launch.json` file:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Debug Python/C++ Script",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${env:CONDA_PREFIX}/bin/python",
      "args": ["${workspaceFolder}/path/to/script.py"],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "PYTHONPATH",
          "value": "${workspaceFolder}/path/to/cpp/extension/for/python:${env:PYTHONPATH}"
        }
      ],
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

where `script.py` is the Python script that makes use of the C++ extension.

Is there a similar way to achieve this when the C++ extension is used from a Jupyter Notebook file instead? My approach above is also quite old. Wondering here if there is a newer and more convenient alternative nowadays (just in case).

Answer (score 1):

The following configuration may need to be modified. More ***launch.json*** configurations can be viewed at any time in the official [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_set-configuration-options).

- `environment` needs to be replaced with the following configuration

  ```json
  "env": {
     "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}/path/to/cpp/extension/for/python:${env:PYTHONPATH}"
  },
  ```
- `program` also needs to be changed to `jupyter`

  ```json
  "program": "${env:CONDA_PREFIX}/bin/jupyter",
  ```
- The `arg` parameter also needs to be modified.

Comment: Thanks JialeDu. It seems GDB cannot debug the program `jupyter`. A pop-up error appears from vscode stating that this file is *"not in executable format: file format not recognized"*.

Comment: If you have detailed error logs, or have clear target requirements. It is recommended that you submit a report on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/new/choose) to get an official response.